# h:selectManyCheckbox with omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter does not preselect the items

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces, selectmanycheckbox

I'm using [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html) 2.0, [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) and [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org).

I have 2 dialogs with `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`. The first dialog creates a new `Course`:

[image]

The `Disciplina`s are presented as:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="disciplinas" 
    value="#{cursoMBean.listaDisciplinasDoCurso}"
    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{cursoMBean.listaTodasDisciplinas}"
        var="disciplina" itemValue="#{disciplina}"
        itemLabel="#{disciplina.nome}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

This works fine. When I select some disciplines and submit the form, then the new `Course` with the selected `Discipline`s is properly inserted in the DB.

However, when I try to retrieve an existing `Course` from the DB, the saved `Discipline`s are not preselected.

[image]

The code is the same:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="disciplinas" 
    value="#{cursoMBean.listaDisciplinasDoCurso}"
    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{cursoMBean.listaTodasDisciplinas}"
        var="disciplina" itemValue="#{disciplina}"
        itemLabel="#{disciplina.nome}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Here's the backing bean:

```
private ArrayList<Disciplina> listaTodasDisciplinas;
private ArrayList<Disciplina> listaDisciplinasDoCurso;

public CursoMBean() {
    if (listaTodasDisciplinas == null) {
        listaTodasDisciplinas = controleDisciplina.consulta();
    }

    if (listaDisciplinasDoCurso == null) {
        listaDisciplinasDoCurso = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
    }
}

// When user selects one Course to edit, this method is called:
public void setSelecionado(Curso selecionado) {
    this.selecionado = selecionado;

    if (selecionado != null) {
        listaTodasDisciplinas = controleDisciplina.consulta();
        listaDisciplinasDoCurso = controleCurso.listaDisciplinasAssociadas(selecionado);
    }
}
```

Here's the `Disciplina` entity:

```
public class Disciplina {

    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public Disciplina() {
    }

    public Disciplina(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        if (!(nome.isEmpty() || nome == " " || nome == "  ")){
            this.nome = nome;
        }
    }

}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you show also code of your entity class (Disciplina)?

Comment: Sure, wait a moment, I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `SelectItemsConverter` relies on `toString()` of the entity to match the selected items. Your entity however doesn't have a `toString()` implemented and is thus relying on default `fqn@hashcode` result which is not the same when two physically different `Disciplina` instances are created even though they have the same value.

You've basically 2 options, also hinted in `SelectItemsConverter` [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) and [javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/converter/SelectItemsConverter.html):

1. Implement a `toString` method that uniquely identifies the entity and which makes sense as an identifier. For example,

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return String.format("%s[id=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getId());
   }
   ```

   *(note that this `toString()` is designed such that you can easily keep it in an abstract base class of all your entities, so that you don't need to copypaste the same over all your entities)*
2. Or, if implementing such a `toString()` is not an option for some reason (e.g. relying on generated classes which can't be modified afterwards (neither the generator template)), then extend the converter as follows:

   ```
   @FacesConverter("disciplinaSelectItemsConverter")
   public class DisciplinaSelectItemsConverter extends SelectItemsConverter {

       @Override
       public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
           Integer id = (value instanceof Disciplina) ? ((Disciplina) value).getId() : null;
           return (id != null) ? String.valueOf(id) : null;
       }

   }
   ```

   *(note: you should really be using `Integer` instead of `int` as ID, the `int` cannot be `null` which is the correct way to represent a brand new and unpersisted entity)*

   And use it as follows

   ```
   <h:selectManyCheckbox ... converter="disciplinaSelectItemsConverter">
   ```

Comment: Thanks Again BalusC! I solved this issue this morning. I made a quick fix and now is working - but is the exactly thing you're doing, but more hard to implement. So, again, you're the best answer :P